# Dropdown Form & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit, onsubmit, window.location

I've been using the following code for a couple of years successfully... basically, it allows the user to select one of two options from the dropdown and gives them an option to click either button 'A' or 'B' to either download (the link is the same for both options), or view the selection online (two separate links).

I now need to add a third option to the list, but not having much luck?  Here's the original code with the new OPTION 3 added, the javascript I've kept as the original as what I've tried so far is not working.

```html
 <form>
  <select class="target">
   <option value="selected" selected="selected">Please choose...</option>
   <option value="option1" value="option3">OPTION 1</option>
   <option value="option2" value="option4">OPTION 2</option>
   <option value="option5" value="option6">OPTION 3</option>
  </select>  
<button type="button" class="button" id='button1'>BUTTON 1</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id='button2'>BUTTON 2</button>
</form>

<script>
var onSubmit1 = function()
{
 window.location = "http://www.link1.com/";
};

var onSubmit2 = function()
{
 window.location = "http://www.link2.com/";
};
var onSubmit3 = function()
{
 window.location = "https://www.link1.com/";
};

var onSubmit4 = function()
{
 window.location = "https://www.link3.com/";;
};

$('.target').change(function(e) {    
 var dropdown = $('.target');
 var text = $( ".target option:selected" ).text();    

 var $button1= $('#button1');
 $button1.unbind('click');

 if(text == "OPTION 1"){
   $button1.click(onSubmit1);
  return;
 }

   $button1.click(onSubmit2);      
});

$('.target').change(function(e) {    
 var dropdown = $('.target');
 var text = $( ".target option:selected" ).text();    

 var $button2= $('#button2');
 $button2.unbind('click');

 if(text == "OPTION 1"){
   $button2.click(onSubmit3);
  return;
 }

   $button2.click(onSubmit4);      
});
</script>
```

Does anyone have any ideas... is it at all possible with the above code?

Comment: What should be done when third drop down selected? Can you please clearify.

Comment: It's done in such a messy way :( You shouldn't define 4 different functions that do the same thing with a different value, and keep reassigning the click event. Why not make the click event always call window.location = somevariable; and update that somevariable with a link onchange of the dropdown menu? And then you're hooking the same event twice with slightly different things, I'm confused.

Comment: Sorry to confuse João Miguel Brandão... javascript is not my strongest, I just found this worked for me a couple of years ago.

planet260, same link as the other two options for button 1, then a new link for button 2.

I can see how this is quite messy (bows his head in shame)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have mentioned, you are massively overusing and overcomplicating this code. It's quite simple if you try it like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <select>
        <option selected disabled>Please choose...</option>
        <option value="http://www.link1.com">OPTION 1</option>
        <option value="http://www.link2.com">OPTION 2</option>
        <option value="http://www.link3.com">OPTION 3</option>
    </select>  
    <button type="button" data-action="follow">GO TO URL</button>
    <button type="button" data-action="download">DOWNLOAD</button>
</form>
```

Note that I've added `data-action` to your buttons, so I can recognise which button does what. I've also changed your values of the select to the actual values you want them to represent, instead of placeholders you have to change.

Just to be correct, I've also 'disabled' your first option so it can't be reselected, and I've removed its value *as it shouldn't have one*. I've added an `id` to the form element, as it allows me to do all without to many classes, and I removed all your classes. I've also ommitted the `="selected"` as you don't need it (unless you are using `XSL` Transforms, which is just... Blurgh.)

```
$("#myForm button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $("#myForm select").val() || false;
    var action = $(this).data("action");
    if(action === "follow" && url){
        /* Follow the link */
        window.location.href = url;
        /* While testing, you could use alert instead of window.location.href
         * as such:
         * alert(action + " " + url)
         */
    } else if(action === "download" && url){
        /* Do the download thing, since I don't know how 
           you're doing that, heres a fictional one: */
        window.location.href = "http://www.link.com/download.php?url=" + url;
        /* While testing, you could use alert instead of window.location.href
         * as such:
         * alert(action + " " + url)
         */
    }
});
```

Now all we need to do is see what button your pressed (tying this to all buttons and then reading the `data-action`) and then executing whatever you wanted to execute. Note that I'm using the line `var url = $("#myForm select").val() || false;` to select either a value or assign it `false` - this is to prevent your 'default' option from triggering the function (I later check if url has a value in the `if` statement).

Comment: Thank you somethinghere... this looks so much neater than my attempt from a few years ago.  I 'think' I understand this... I will go and have a play :-)

Comment: Also note that I have made some amends since the original posting (some tiny errors and I mislabelled the buttons). If you want to test whether it works just replace the `window.location.href = url;` with and alert (`alert("go to: " + url)` and `alert("download " + url);` for the second one) and you'll see it does the trick.

Comment: >> If you want to test whether it works just replace the window.location.href = url; with and alert (alert("go to: " + url) and alert("download " + url); for the second one) and you'll see it does the trick.

Thanks again @somethingthere will this work for 3x links, each download was just a static link to a .PDF nothing too fancy

Comment: It will work with (0 to infinity) if you want to add them all. The code is seperated from the data - it will check what is selected when you click the button and then use whatever the `value` is as the url. This makes it endlessly scalable.

Comment: @user1735193 You shouldn't use stack overflows edit like you did, so I have rejected it. I have added the code to my post, though. But yes, you used it correctly. If this works for you, could you mark it is the correct answer?

Comment: Thanks @somethingthere I've marked as correct answer!  You're help has been both informative and invaluable.  I think one of the reasons I did this the way I did previously was because I had to add tracking to each link (_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Link 1', 'Clicked', 'Link 1']);)  can this be worked in to your solution?

Comment: I've just noticed a little 'problem' with the code, you have to add the `&& url` to the second `if` as well, otherwise the default will always trigger 'download'. I'll amend my post. Thanks for marking!

Comment: as brilliant as this solution is, I don't think I'll be able to use it as I need to add the tracking code to both links (_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Link1', 'Clicked', 'Link1Download']);)  I guess I can add this to the onclick in the form?  But what about the (follow) link?  Is there a way I can place the code on each option?  I think this is why I did it in such a convoluted way originally :(

Comment: You could simple run that script before you send the user away to view or download. After `var action = $(this).data("action")` you can add `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', action + " > " + url, 'Clicked', 'Link1Download']);`, or whatever. You have the info (namely the action AND the url), so just insert it in the correct place of the `_gaq_push()` function array and it should report fine. `_gaq.push()` does not _need_ to be ran inside an onclick attribute.

Comment: Thank you @somethinghere, I've edited your code and added the tracking code where I think it should be... is this correct & will this still return the same results do you think?

Comment: I didn't receive an edit. Look, you can do whatever you want with the info we extracted from the select box when the click event happens. I'm not very well versed in google analytics, but you can simply call the tracking function there and pass it some data to track that data. It really isn't that hard, let alone rocket science, so play around a bit. Google analytics is _just a function_ so you can call it there instead of on click. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @somethinghere for your time and patience this afternoon, you've really helped my understanding of this.  Much appreciated!